# Preload sparse data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been experimenting with a few ways of loading sparse data into Tensorflow. It's my understanding that preloading data instead of feeding it via `feed_dict` is more performant, so I would like to try and do this with my sparse data.

For dense data, I can follow this example: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#preloaded-data.

But how can this be done with sparse data? I guess I could put the indices and corresponding values into two separate variables and then go on with the slice_input_producer -> batch. But then I loose the information of which indices corresponds to a sample, so the batches will be corrupt.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Sparse tensors are mostly supported now in `tf.data`. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13766